# Inner function does not assign value to element dynamically created by outer function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a search result dynamically added below the form through ajax call using parameter given in the form. I can add results using a table, but in these results I have client ids where I need Name, so I again use ajax call for each client id which return success but can not assign the values to corresponding table field. Below is my code, what is wrong here?

```
var stopMulti = 0;
$('#salesreport-end_date').change(function(){
    var endDate = $(this).val();
    var startDate = $('#salesreport-start_date').val();
    var param = startDate+'#'+endDate+'#date';
    if(stopMulti == 0){
        $.get('index.php?r=reports/sales-report/sales-report',{ id : param }, function(data){
            var sReport = JSON.parse(data);
            if(typeof sReport != 'undefined'){
                if(sReport.length != 0){
                    $('<div id="sales-report-div-1" class="col-sm-12"><h2 id ="sales-report-heading-1">Sales Report</h2></div>').insertAfter('#sub-button-div');
                    $('<table class="table-bordered text-center col-sm-12"><tr id="sales-report-row-head"><th class="text-center">Invoice Number</th><th class="text-center">Client Name</th><th class="text-center">Company Name</th><th class="text-center">Phone</th><th class="text-center">Net Total</th><th class="text-center">VAT</th><th class="text-center">Total</th></tr></table>').insertAfter('#sales-report-heading-1');
                    $('<br><br>').insertAfter('#sales-report-div-1');

                    var count = 0;
                    for(var i = 0; i < sReport.length; i++){
                        $('<tr><td id=sales-report-col-1'+count+'></td><td id=sales-report-col-2'+count+'></td><td id=sales-report-col-3'+count+'></td><td id=sales-report-col-4'+count+'></td><td id=sales-report-col-5'+count+'><td id=sales-report-col-6'+count+'></td><td id=sales-report-col-7'+count+'></td></tr></div>').insertAfter('#sales-report-row-head');
                        $('#sales-report-col-1'+count).html(sReport[i].invoice_id);
                        $.get('index.php?r=reports/sales-report/get-client',{ id : sReport[i].client_id}, function(client){
                            var client = JSON.parse(client);
                            $('#sales-report-col-2'+count).text(client.client_name);
                            $('#sales-report-col-3'+count).text(client.company_name);
                            $('#sales-report-col-4'+count).text(client.telephon);
                        });
                        $('#sales-report-col-5'+count).html(sReport[i].sub_total);
                        $('#sales-report-col-6'+count).html(sReport[i].taxrate);
                        $('#sales-report-col-7'+count).html(sReport[i].invoice_total);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    stopMulti = 1;      
});
```

That is I am getting blank fields for client name, company name and telephone.
Firebug does not find any error in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.get` callback function will be called asynchronously, and therefor any value like `count` will be changed before the `.get` returns.

A simple technique to overcome this is to use anonymous function, so your function should look like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sReport.length; i++)
{
    f = function(i,count)
    {
        ... rest of your code
    }
    f(i,count);
    count++;
}
```

Here is a general example: https://jsfiddle.net/BentalSW/auyLq7rp/

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `count` inside the inner AJAX Callback because by the time those asynchronous calls complete `count` will equal `sReport.length` and the wrong divs will be updated.

Use a `.forEach` loop instead of the `for` loop:

```
sReport.forEach(function(report, count) {
    ...
});
```

This will give you a value of `count` that is correctly bound to the current iteration count.

NB: it shouldn't be necessary to call `JSON.parse` on data that's already in JSON format - jQuery will do that for you automatically.

Comment: Well, even if I don't parse the second ajax result still it does not work.

Comment: downvoter - please explain - this is a perfectly good (if not easier to understand) solution than using an anonymous closure around the call.